# Django update field using a form in a many to many relationship

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-forms, django-views

I have two models in many to many relationships. I want to use a form to update fields, the form has a drop list when authorizers have an option to reject or approve the leave. once the leave has been approved I want to be able to adjust the Leave_current_balance. However, I am getting the error message: 'float' object has no attribute 'save' from the line of code  current_balance.save()

```html
def unitDirectorForm(request,id):
    if request.method=='POST':
     
        getstaffid=NewLeave.objects.get(id=id)
        form = DirectorForm(request.POST, instance=getstaffid)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            total_days = getstaffid.Total_working_days
            current_balance = getstaffid.user.leave_balance.Leave_current_balance
            diff_balance = current_balance - total_days
            current_balance = diff_balance
            current_balance.save()
            return HttpResponse('You have successfuly Authorise the leave')

    else:
        
        form=DirectorForm()
        balance_form = leavebbalanceForm()

    return render(request,'managerauthorisedform.html',{'form':form})
    
                                                  
    
class LeaveBalance(models.Model):
    user=models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,primary_key=True,)
    Leave_current_balance= models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True, default=None)
    Year=models.CharField(max_length=100,default='')
    def __unicode__(self):
             return  self.Year


class NewLeave(models.Model):
      user=models.ForeignKey(User,default='',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   leave_balance=models.ManyToManyField(Leave_Balance)
    Leave_type=models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=False,default='')
    Total_working_days=models.FloatField(null=True,  blank=False)
    leave=(
        ('annual','annual'),
        ('sick','sick'),

    )

  Leave_type=models.CharField(max_length=100,choices=leave,blank=False,default='')
    def __unicode__(self):
        return  self.Leave_type
```

```html
class DirectorForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=NewLeave
        fields=('Director_Authorization_Status','Authorized_by_Director','Date_Authorized',)
        widgets={
            'Date_Authorized':DateInput()
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

So first of all, I don't know what your `form` looks like, but I am going to guess.  First of all, your error is occurring because you're trying to call the `save` function on a variable that is of type `float`.  You should be saving the form, not a number.  You need to do all of the calculations from line `total_days...` to `current_balance = diff...` prior to calling `form.save()`.  After finishing those calculations, you should assign the `current_balance` to `form.fields['Leave_current_balance']`, and then save the form.

Comment: Thanks, i did, current_balance=form.fields['Leave_current_balance']
            current_balance.save() but i got the error: u'Leave_current_balance'

Comment: I think it is throwing error because Leave_current_balance is on a different model which is not part of form

Comment: then it would be `leave_balance` that you're looking for.